# VirtualHost redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com not working

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, https, redirect

I'm running several different Virtual hosts on Apache2. Each has its own .conf file. I'm trying to redirect all traffic to https://example.com as that is where I have my certificates. https://example.com, http://example.com, and http://www.example.com all work fine. However, https://www.example.com is not working correctly. Here is my .conf layout:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
... (server/ssl configuration)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Define "not working correctly" please, what exactly do you see when you try and go to the site to try and get the redirect?

Comment: There is no redirect, it stays at "https:// www.example.com"  which is not a valid location.

Comment: One other point, while two of the virtual hosts run into this problem, a third virtual host actually correctly redirects. They all use the same type of configuration (shown above), so I'm left scratching my head and asking for advice from the community.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, if you don't have a correct certificate for https://www.example.com. In the (ssl) process of client-server handshake, establishment of secure connection is the first step.

If you have certificate for https://www.example.com add it to the .conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName www.example.com 
        Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com.root-bundle.crt
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have some data that contradicts this. While two of the virtual hosts run into this problem, a third virtual host actually correctly redirects. They all use the same type of configuration (shown above), so I'm left scratching my head and asking for advice from the community.

Comment: Ok, the above example is from my Apache2 configuration. If I remove SSL certificate from it, redirection stuck on and the browser gives a message like "Your connection is not private". The reason is that I'm asking for secure "https" connections but the server doesn't provide correct data to be done. You can do an experiment. Go to https://www.startssl.com/ , there you can generate free ssl certificate for "example.com" and "www.example.com", then use them in this scenario. It will work.

Comment: So, when you use https connection and redirection, steps of it are: (1) establishment of secure "https" connection; (2) redirecting. You can't miss the first step, because of the idea of secure connection.

Comment: But If you can find other way I will use it with my pleasure!